# C# structural highlighting in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm looking for an add-in to VS2008 that can enable structural highlighting (**vertical** lines in blocks of code) in the C# code editor.

I tried out CodeRush, but while the structural highlighting was great, I was annoyed with all the other stuff in CodeRush. No matter how much I disabled in the options, I couldn't quite get rid of it.

So I'm looking for another add-in that enables structural highlighting and (ideally) nothing else. Know of any?

Comment: > I was annoyed with all the other stuff in CodeRush If you can provide additional details on features that annoy you, I can help you to disable them :)

Comment: This question is a great candidate for the [visual-studio-2008] tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While browsing the [ViEmu](http://viemu.com) site, I saw the [Codekana](http://codekana.com) product which looks like it may do what you want.

Comment: Very nice!  My current gig requires that we do .NET CF 3.5 work in VS 2008, so this gives me a lot of features that I miss from my beloved VS 201x.

Comment: Note that CodeKana is free now but not FOSS, from [their store page](http://www.codekana.com/store.html): "Codekana is now free! Just download it and enjoy it. Codekana will become open source as soon as we have the time to tidy up the codebase and upload it somewhere." I think it's been about 10 years since they said that. On startup the addon asks me for a license but nothing bad seemed to happen when I didn't give them one.

Answer (score 2):

Is the Indentation Guide from the [SlickEdit Free Gadgets](http://www.slickedit.com/content/view/441) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a JetBrains resharper to handle this as well (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and found it to be a great tool for much more tasks.

If you need just highlighting, that may be npt your case though

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper (www.jetbrains.com) can outline a scope. If the scope is too large for the editor it displays the first line (heading) of the scope when the cursor stays on the closing curly brace/parenthesis.